# Making a calender with JavaScript, how can I make it so that the loop starts in a specific date at 1 and not just hide the index

Tags: javascript

Making a calendar with JavaScript, how can I make it so that the loop starts in a specific date at 1 and not just hide the index.

for example, when I select february it starts at Wednesday with the number 4, I just want the 4 to become a 1 and count upwards, I don't really care about the positioning at the moment.

Please help

```
    <script>
        for (var i = 12; i > 0; i--) {
            var select = document.getElementById("month");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i - 1;
            option.innerText = i;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        for (var i = 2019; i > 1899; i--) {
            var select = document.getElementById("year");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i - 1;
            option.innerText = i;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        function printDays(){
            var days = document.getElementById("days");
                days.innerHTML = '';
            var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
            var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
            var date = 32 - (new Date(year , month , 32).getDate());
            var day = new Date(year , month).getDay();
            var d = 0;
            var d1 = 0;
            console.log(day);
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                        d++;
                        d1++;
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                            if(d1 >= day && d <= date){
                                td.innerText = d;
                            }
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                days.appendChild(tr);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/  Take care in spelling the name of the tools you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you want to do. But if you want the days to start always with day 1. you change your code like that

```
   function printDays(){
            var days = document.getElementById("days");
                days.innerHTML = '';
            var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
            var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
            var date = 32 - (new Date(year , month , 32).getDate());
            var day = new Date(year , month).getDay();
            var d = 0;
            var d1 = 0;
            console.log(day);
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                  d++;
        //move d1 inside the if and use it to display days
                  var td = document.createElement("td");
                  if (d >= day && d <= date) {
                    d1++;
                    td.innerText = (d1).toString();
                  }
                tr.appendChild(td);
              }
                days.appendChild(tr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Its not this, you know how each month starts in a different day of the week, I want each month to begin at that specific weekday, I don't want it to be completely identical, I just want each month to start at 1 of that certain weekday and not just start at Sunday as 1 and go until 32. Basically when I select february the calender hides the numbers between 1 to 3 and and goes from 4 to 28, I want this 4 to become a 1 and go until 25 .I am sorry if I am not explaining it properly. I hope you write soon ! Thank you

Comment: ah ok i will change the code another time. d and d1 in your code have the same values

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        for (var i = 12; i > 0; i--) {
            var select = document.getElementById("month");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i - 1;
            option.innerText = i;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        for (var i = 2019; i > 1899; i--) {
            var select = document.getElementById("year");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i - 1;
            option.innerText = i;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        function printDays(){
            var days = document.getElementById("days");
                days.innerHTML = '';
            var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
            var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
            var date = 32 - (new Date(year , month , 32).getDate());
            var day = new Date(year , month).getDay();
            var d = 0;
            var d1 = 0;
            console.log(day);
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                        d1++;
                        //d++;
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                            if(d1 >= day && d <= date){
                            ++d;
                                td.innerText = d;
                            }
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                days.appendChild(tr);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Sir, you dont have to help me anymore I solved it by myself, thanks for your attention though I am very thankful.